# Apache virtual host set up not working for a single website

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, website, linode

I have a Linode VPS hosting several websites. Using Linode guides, I created folders to place files and created an apache .conf file holding the virtual host configuration for each website.

This would be a normal setup which has worked for many sites actually loading:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
 ServerAdmin me@business.com
 ServerName  www.xolo.co
 ServerAlias xolo.co

 # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
 DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
 DocumentRoot /var/www/xolo/public_html
 # Log file locations
 LogLevel warn
 ErrorLog  /var/www/xolo/log/error.log
 CustomLog /var/www/xolo/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Each site has its own apache .conf file(I mean site abc.com has, under folder sites-available/abc.conf, and so on, containing the above code).

However, there's an specific site to which I've done the same steps(twice) and when I point a placeholder domain we own to test whether the site loads fine, noting happens.

There's not database connection error, nothing at all. I just get a blank site.

I've already

- Checked the domain loads a different site (this is because the domain has its own apache conf file)
- Checked folder permissions (the look pretty ok to me comparing to working folders)
- Redoing the steps of setting a website in the Linode VPS I did before to many websites.

I just run out of options and don't know where to exactly look for.

Any instructions, links to look for, or straight solutions are highly appreciated.

Comment: What does tail /var/www/xolo/log/error.log and /var/www/xolo/log/access.log tell you?

Comment: I'd check your DNS settings - the IP your ServerName resolves to appears to resolve to GoDaddy.

Comment: @thexacre I got this `[Sat Jan 24 09:56:49.108750 2015] [:error] [pid 3070] [client 190.146.26.120:50787] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/rincondavila/public_html/includes/database/database.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/rincondavila/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 2475`   

I'm already googling about this